Prove that the set $x_n(t) = \{n^{-t - 1/2}, n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ is compact in the space $C([0, 1])$.
Prove that the set $x_n(t) = \{n^{-t - 1/2}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is compact in the space $C([0, 1])$. I know that in order to prove that the set is compact, I need to prove that it is equi-continuious, but I am stuck at that part.

Edit your question to include the zero function/uniform limit. Otherwise, you might as well be asking if ${1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.


You don't "need" to prove equicontinuity: see Andrew's answer. 2) You should include your efforts to prove it, to explain what stops you. It doesn't seem difficult: see Tomasz's answer. At least write the definition.


I followed the definition of equi-continuity $\forall \epsilon > 0, , \exists \delta > 0 , \text{ such that } , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, , \forall t_1, t_2 \in T, , |t_1 - t_2| < \delta \implies |x_n(t_1) - x_n(t_2)| < \epsilon. $
I tried to find $ \delta $ using $ \epsilon$

Equicontinuity: For $n> 0$, consider the derivative $x_n^\prime(t) = -\ln n \cdot n^{-t - 1/2}$. The functions $|x_n^\prime|$ are decreasing, hence they attain their value at 0, which is $\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \leqslant 1$. Consequently, all $x_n$ are 1-Lipschitz functions (the absolute values of their derivatives are bounded by 1), so they are equicontinous because of that.
For closedness, you need $x_0 = 0$ to be included.

+1 but the monotonicity argument is superfluous. $\forall t\ge0\quad n^{-t}\le1$ is easier and sufficient. Similarly, $\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}\le1$ is less obvious than: bounded since convergent (to $0$).

Clearly, $\|x_n\|_u \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, $\{x_n:n\in N\}$ is compact if and only if $0\in N$ and we agree to set $x_0 = 0$.
